# is there a SQL Prompt like plugin for VS 2008

Tags: sql, visual-studio, plugins, intellisense

I like to use the SQL Tools in VS but I would like to have some intellisense for SQL, with sql manager I can get the Redgate SQL prompt but I would like to stay in VS, any Ideas?

Edit:
is there anything other then Redgate SQL prompt? that dose error checking like the way R# or dev express?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Red-Gate SQL Prompt (at least more recent versions, I believe 3.x and up) also works inside Visual Studio. I don't think you need another extra tool, really.

See the [Red-Gate SQL Prompt feature page](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm)

It says clearly:

> Integrates with SSMS, SSMS Express, Query Analyzer and **Visual Studio**

Marc

Answer (score 1):

With Red Gate SQL Prompt you also will stay in VS and this product supports now just VS 2008.
[SQL Prompt web page](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm)

If you don't like it I can propose you to try  [SQL Assist](http://roundpolygons.com/) or [SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/overview.html). I use this tool and as for me it's really reliable one.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from tools mentioned above there is a pretty neat tool from ApexSQL called “Complete”. I think this article can explain further http://blog.apexsql.com/ssms-intellisense-add-in-and-ssms-intellisense/

And the [tool itself](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQL Prompt 3.x and 4.x beta for sure work with Visual Studio 2005/2008

You can download the 4.x beta to play with, and visit their forum if you have any question/problem. Red Gate people are very nice and helpful
http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewforum.php?f=98